# Rooting Lenovo A600Plus Running on Lolipop 5.0

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, rooting, root-access

Previously before the OTA update I have rooted my phone with [KingRoot](http://androidxda.com/download-kingroot-application).

While I was Updating the rooting creating problem for me so I unrooted the Phone.

Now I want to root it again I want to know will the [Kingroot](http://androidxda.com/download-kingroot-application) still Works or not.

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: i have only one phone not in a mood to destroy it